# Animated scrollto effect jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I used this plug-in and got rid of some unnecessary code, for some reasons it does nor work in FireFox.

Original source: http://djpate.com/2011/01/01/animated-scrollto-effect-jquery-plugin/

my code:

```
(function (a) {
a.fn.slideto = function (b) {
    var c = {
        slide_duration: "slow",
        offset: 0
    }, b = a.extend(c, b);
    return this.each(function () {
        var c = !1;
        obj = a(this), a("body").animate({
            scrollTop: obj.offset().top + b.offset
        })
    })
}
})($);
```

Code used to call the plug-in:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#scroll").click(function(){
                $("#results").slideto();
            });
        });
```

Comment: hi guys, never mind I just found this little code which works nicely, I am just going to add a click event to it.

Comment: $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#results").offset().top
    }, 2000);

Comment: lolz I was trying to find the solution :P http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/KXPdd/2/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is some browsers expect you to scroll the html and others the body. 
They even change this expectation if on [Quirk's mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

You can use the [jquery.scrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) plugin which handles that for you.

You need to include the plugin and then something like this will do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#scroll").click(function() {
    $(window).scrollTo("#results", {duration:"slow", offset:0});
    return false;
  });
});
```

Just added the settings you seem to be interested in, it provides a lot more.

BTW, you might want to check [jquery.localScroll](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.localScroll) which sits on top on scrollTo and makes you links scroll automatically based on anchors (f.e <a href="#results">)

Cheers